# How can I have a dialog box in jsf?

Tags: jsf, dialog, modal-dialog

I need to have a dialog box in my jsf application which should pop up on click of a link or an image. I need to put signup form on this dialog box and submit should submit this form. Is this possible with JSF?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using JavaScript yourself.

However, check this out (PrimeFaces): [LightBox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/lightBox.xhtml) and [Dialog](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

Try a [rich:modalPanel](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_modalPanel.html).